# Can I combine these two .htaccess files into one?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, url-rewriting

It is possible to combine these two .htaccess files into one? They deal with two separate PHP apps that have completely separate pretty URL handling. The reason why I want to try one is because mod_security is throwing errors and completely ignoring my second .htaccess file in the chain here, but seems to not have a problem with one .htaccess file.

So, if one goes to /blah, the first app handles the pretty URL handling. But if one goes to /members/blah, the second app handles the pretty URL handling. However, note the -f and -d parameters where we check for actual file or directory paths and permit those through.

In the root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^members$ /members/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^members/(.*)$ /memberapp/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

In /memberapp:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /memberapp/index.php [QSA]
```

**EDIT 1:**

So, here's the mapping example:

```
domain.com = domain.com/index.php
domain.com/ = domain.com/index.php
domain.com/?test=test = domain.com/index.php
domain.com/members/test.png = domain.com/memberapp/test.png (file exists)
domain.com/members/dir1 = domain.com/memberapp/dir1 (directory exists)
domain.com/members/dir1/ = domain.com/memberapp/dir1 (ditto)
domain.com/test = domain.com/index.php
domain.com/members/login = domain.com/memberapp/index.php
domain.com/members/test.php = domain.com/memberapp/test.php (file exists)
domain.com/dir1 = domain.com/dir1 (directory exists)
domain.com/dir1/ = domain.com/dir1 (directory exists)
domain.com/test.png = domain.com/test.png (file exists)
domain.com/members/login?test=test = domain.com/memberapp/index.php
```

Comment: ¿How are the incoming URIs in both cases? From the rules looks like `domain.com/members/` should map to `domain.com/index.php` and `domain.com/memberapp/` should map to `domain.com/memberapp/index.php` but I am not good at guessing. Some URI examples will help.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA I will edit my original post to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^members$ /members/ [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^members/(.*)$ /memberapp/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^membersapp/ /memberapp/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Will take me some time to test due to my time constraints for a new job. I'll check this out soon, however.